# How to set index.html to redirect wget query to an other page/file?

Tags: redirect, wget, redirection

If my server is at `example.com`, running

```
$ wget example.com
```

will only download the file `index.html`. How can I make `wget` either

- download another file instead of index.html
- download this file along index,html

I have all redirection I could find `pubkey.asc` is my file):

1. ```
   <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="seconds; url=pubkey.asc ">
   ```
2. ```
    <script language="javascript">
   window.location.href = "http://example.com"
   ```
3. ```
   <link rel="canonical" href="pubkey.asc"/>
   ```
4. ```
   <script> document.location.href="pubkey.asc";</script>
   ```
5. `<script>window.location.href='pubkey.asc';</script>`
6. ```
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=pubkey.asc" />
   ```

---

PS: I am posting here instead of web.stackexchange since `wget` mechanism is involved.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=pubkey.asc">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Combined with 
`wget -r http://example.com`

downloads both index.html and pubkey.asc